# Key-per-file config in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I am trying to get this to work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#key-per-file-configuration-provider

But I am not having any success when it comes to using hierarchical file names. I want to map some value to `Logging:Backend:URL`, but I can only get it to work on top-level settings, when I'm not using any `:`.

My directory contains this file:

```
Logging_Backend_URL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Judging by the docs the filenames should have 2 underscores and you only have one

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @faso that was it. can't believe i missed it. post your solution as an answer and i'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#key-per-file-configuration-provider) the filenames should have 2 underscores and you only have one:

> The double-underscore (__) is used as a configuration key delimiter in file names. For example, the file name Logging__LogLevel__System produces the configuration key Logging:LogLevel:System.